# Why is fetch() not working on vscode debugger?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, fetch

Running live server on VS Code gives me the expected output, I'm fetching a txt file.

```
      let file = "/files/mensaje.txt"

      fetch (file)
      .then(x => x.text())
      .then(y => document.getElementById("letrero").innerHTML = y);
```

[Works as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKeFC.png)

Works fine, but if I try to debug it it throws a "Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to fetch"

[Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dskkp.png)

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at test (c:\Users\User\Desktop\Desarrollo Profesional\Cursos Desarrollador\JS Curso 2022\important_concepts_fetch.html:32:7)
    at onclick (c:\Users\User\Desktop\Desarrollo Profesional\Cursos Desarrollador\JS Curso 2022\important_concepts_fetch.html:16:42)
    --- Promise.then ---
    at test (c:\Users\User\Desktop\Desarrollo Profesional\Cursos Desarrollador\JS Curso 2022\important_concepts_fetch.html:34:8)
    at onclick (c:\Users\User\Desktop\Desarrollo Profesional\Cursos Desarrollador\JS Curso 2022\important_concepts_fetch.html:16:42)
test @ c:\Users\User\Desktop\Desarrollo Profesional\Cursos Desarrollador\JS Curso 2022\important_concepts_fetch.html:32:7
```

I was expecting to get the same output on debug mode. I'm just starting to learn on developing, so pretty new to a lot of concepts and how they work. This is not the only time this has happened to me, other programs work fine just using the liver server from VS Code, when I try to debugg i get errors.

This is the launch.json if it helps.

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
  
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Open important_concepts_fetch.html",
      "file": "c:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Desarrollo Profesional\\Cursos Desarrollador\\JS Curso 2022\\important_concepts_fetch.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If VSCode uses nodejs for debugging, fetch probably doesn't exist there.

Comment: `fetch` was only introduced into Node 18 earlier this year.

Comment: If `fetch` didn’t exist, you’d get a _“`ReferenceError`: `fetch` is not defined”_. However, failing to fetch sounds like a network error which might be caused by the file not being allowed to be read or by the file not being found. Why it says _“Uncaught `TypeError` `TypeError`”_ (not the kind of error I expected and the word being repeated), though, I don’t know.